# Как посчитать строки каждого файла отдельно?

Tags: java, файлы

```
public class SearchFiles {
    static ArrayList<File> FilesFind = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String mask,  search;
        int count = 0;
        Scanner DIR_NAME = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner MASK_NAME = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Input name directory :");
        getFileslist(DIR_NAME.nextLine());
        System.out.println("Input mask :");
        mask = MASK_NAME.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Find files is :" );
        // цикл поиска файла
        for (File fill : FilesFind) {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fill));
                while ((search=reader.readLine())!= null){
                    if (search.contains(mask) && !search.isEmpty()){
                          count++;
                        System.out.println("Name files : " + fill.getName() + " --- > " + " String : " + count);
                    }

                }
            reader.close();
        }
    }
    public static void getFileslist(String nameDirectory){
        File f = new File(nameDirectory);
        for (File s : f.listFiles()) {
            if (s.isFile()) {
                FilesFind.add(s);
            } else if (s.isDirectory()) {
                getFileslist(s.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Вашем примере за количество строчек отвечает переменная **count**, но как видно, в конце программы эта переменная равна общему количеству строк во всех файлах.

Для того, чтобы посчитать отдельно для каждого файла, надо

```
int count = 0;
```

заменить на

```
Map<File,Integer> fileMap = new HashMap<>();
```

И немного переписать цикл

```
for (File fill: FilesFind) {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fill));
    int count = 0;
    while ((search = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (search.contains(mask) && !search.isEmpty()) {
            count++;
            System.out.println("Name files : " + fill.getName() + " --- > " + " String : " + count);
        }
    }
    fileMap.put(fill, count);
    reader.close();
}
```

**P.S.** если не нужно нигде больше использовать количество строк для каждого файла, то мапу можно удалить и просто создавать переменную **count** в цикле for